# Compare the keys of two dictionaries present inside two lists and subtracting their respective values

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
a=[{"aaa":10},{"bbb":20}]
b=[{"aaa":2},{"bbb":5}]
```

I want to subtract the dictionaries present inside the lists and subtract the value if their key matches and store the results into variables.

Expected result

```
 var_1=8        i.e (aaa(10-2))
 var_2=15       i.e (bbb(20-5))
```

I am able to achieve the result by iterating thorough both the lists, then the dictionaries inside the lists and comparing their keys. If the keys matches then subtracting the values and storing the result into a variable

Can anybody suggest if there is any predefined function to achieve the result in one or two statements, rather than writing many nested loops.

Comment: What do you intend to do with no-matches?

Comment: Why do your dictionaries only have one key? It looks like `a` and `b` should be dictionaries instead of lists of dictionaries.

Comment: In addition to "why do you have a list of single-key dictionaries", and "what about non-matches", I have to add - do you know for certain that the first list (`a` in the example) will always be the minuend, and `b` will always be the subtrahend?

Comment: Ya , There are few codes ahead that will take the absolute value , so no worries for the -ve sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...by using list comprehension.

```
final_result =  [{key:dic_a[key]- dic_b[key]} for dic_a in a for dic_b in b for key in dic_a if key in dic_b]
```

result:

```
[{'aaa': 8}, {'bbb': 15}]
```

Is this the u r desired output??

Comment: Note that this answer is working roughly for O(NxM) where N, M are sizes of lists, while constructing a dict from each list and evaluating result for roughly O(N+M)

Comment: Second, not related, you'll won't get results for keys from b not represented in a. However OP still didn't clarify this and other edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `collections.Counter` to convert your lists to Counters, and substract them the way you like. Following code will threat missing values as zeros:

```
import collections 

def substract_lists(a, b):
    def sum_dicts(*dicts):
        rv = collections.Counter()
        for d in dicts: rv.update(**d)
        return rv
    a2c = sum_dicts(*a)
    b2c = sum_dicts(*b)
    return {k: a2c[k] - b2c[k] for k in set(a2c) | set(b2c)}
```

Demo

```
>>> substract_lists([{'aaa': 10}, {'ccc': -20}], [{'aaa': 2}, {'bbb': 5}])
{'aaa': 8, 'bbb': -5, 'ccc': -20}
```